# Firefox Web extension toDataURL operation is insecure

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm getting this error when I try to load remote image and call **toDataURL** in the background js code file.

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

I tried playing with CORS but it doesn't helped. Any solution or this? Btw this code works fine in Chrome extension.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: try downloading the image data via xhr or fetch instead

Comment: @the8472 I can't, this is jsPDF addimage.js plugin code it contains this line: canvas.toDataURL...